# Non-capturing lambda seems to nevertheless capture the enclosing instance

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, language-lawyer

I wrote this code:

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main();
    }

    private Main() throws Exception {
        Supplier<Thread> supplier = (Supplier<Thread> & Serializable) () -> new Thread() {};
        new ObjectOutputStream(System.out).writeObject(supplier);
    }
}
```

If I run it, I'll get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Main
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at Main.<init>(Main.java:28)
```

However, my understanding is that I properly made the lambda `Serializable` and I declared it such that it doesn't refer to any surrounding context, being therefore a *non-capturing* lambda. Yet the `Main` instance is captured and the result of the lambda expression fails to be serialized. I realize I'm declaring an anonymous class inside the lambda, but I would expect the lambda instance itself to be its enclosing instance, not the surrounding `Main` type.

Is this behavior expected by the Java Language Specification and, if yes, how come?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your lambda expression’s body, you have the anonymous class declaration `new Thread() {}` and you are not in a `static` context, so this expression implicitly captures `this`, which has the same meaning within the lambda expression as outside of it, per [JLS §15.27.2, Lambda Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, the meaning of names and the `this` and `super` keywords appearing in a lambda body, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, are the same as in the surrounding context (except that lambda parameters introduce new names).
>
> *The transparency of `this` (both explicit and implicit) in the body of a lambda expression - that is, treating it the same as in the surrounding context - allows more flexibility for implementations, and prevents the meaning of unqualified names in the body from being dependent on overload resolution.*

Since the surrounding context determines the behavior of the anonymous class, you can easily fix the issue by using a `static` context to create a nested class instead:

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        write();
    }

    static void write() throws Exception {
        Supplier<Thread> supplier = (Supplier<Thread> & Serializable)() -> new Thread() {};
        new ObjectOutputStream(System.out).writeObject(supplier);
    }
}
```

Then, no surrounding instance will be captured.

Note that this can be seen as the general idea of lambda expressions, to define functions as expressions having exactly the same meaning as within the context they are written, except for the introduction of function parameters. The generation of an instance of a functional interface is only the vehicle to get this concept into the Java programming language in a compatible and useful way, but not a concept to influence the meaning of the lambda expression.

Comment: so this is not as much about lambda as about the anonymous inner class and the `this` that it captures?

Comment: I'd say it's also about the not-so-obvious semantics of the transparent `this` semantics in lambdas. It's the interaction of both. If anon classes had a more refined definition of capturing, this would not be such an issue.

Comment: `expressions having exactly the same meaning as within the context they are written`---except for `return`, `break` and `continue`. Not having them precludes some important use cases of looping with lambdas and limits the utility of `forEach`, as an example.

Comment: @Eugene: The OP already understood that `new Thread() {}` will capture an outer `this` instance, the key point is that the outer `this` it will capture, is the `Main` instance, which is a lambda specific behavior. So that subclass of `Thread` will be an anonymous inner class of `Main`, not of an anonymous `Supplier` implementation. Since `new Thread() {}` needs a `Main` instance to capture, the lambda expression will be a capturing lambda expression.

Comment: @William F. Jameson: supporting `break` and `continue` consistently would be a challenge, technically and semantically. But that’s not a contradiction as `break` and `continue` don’t have a different meaning, they are simply not supported that way. A different thing is `return` or `throw`, indeed. But note that these are statements, not expressions, so for pure expressions, that picture works.

Comment: Every lambda expression is a pure expression evaluating to an instance of the functional interface. I thought that was the expression your sentence refers to. So you actually meant just the lambda body as an expression? But that still leaves the conceptual gap open. Compare that to Scala, where the lambda blends in so deeply that you can't even distinguish it from a "block". Scala doesn't have the `break` and `continue` keywods, though, and for precisely the same reason as here.

Comment: @William F. Jameson: yes, I was talking about the lambda body. If it is not an expression, but a block, it doesn’t match the semantics of the surrounding context exactly, i.e. if there are `return` or `throw` statements, but we know, Java has its limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply:

- anonymous classes always reference enclosing instance when created in a non-static context
- `this` in lambda is the lambda's enclosing instance (not the lambda itself)

From this follows, that anonymous class inside a lambda expression captures the instance enclosing the lambda expression. In your example it captures the instance of `Main`, which is not serializable.

Possible solutions:

1. create the lambda in static context: in a static method or assign to a static field
2. replace the anonymous class with `static` nested class:

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main();
    }

    private Main() throws Exception {
        Supplier<Thread> supplier = (Supplier<Thread> & Serializable) MyThread::new;
        new ObjectOutputStream(System.out).writeObject(supplier);
    }

    private static class MyThread extends Thread {
    }
}
```

Comment: The Java Language Specification reserves the term `inner` class for the `nested` class that is not a `static nested` class. The class in your post is an example of a `static nested` class, whereas the class in Holger's post is an `inner class declared in a static context` (which is _not_ a `static nested` class).

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson, you are right with the spec, but IntelliJ offers to "create inner class" and actually creates a "nested static" class. The usage is not well settled within the community. Anyway, I updated the answer.